# How to hide a CSS element if a class exists in a div elsewhere?

Tags: css

How can I use CSS to apply `display: none;` to a div if a class exists in a div that is not the parent or sibling to the div on which I want to apply `display: none` to?

So i want to apply this css:

```css
.sticky-button { display: none;}
```

when this class `.is-open` is available anywhere else on the page.

`.sticky-button` is not a child or sibling of .is-open.

Here's the code I tried but didn't work:

```js
var b = document.querySelector('.is-open');

if (b) {
  document.querySelector('.sticky-button').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Can i see the code so that I can help you?

Comment: Yes, so i want to apply this css:

.sticky-button { display: none;}

when this class '.is-open' is available anywhere else on the page.

.sticky-button is not a child or sibling of .is-open.

Here's the code i tried but didn't work:

var b = document.querySelector('.is-open');

if (b) {
  document.querySelector('.sticky-button').style.display = 'none';

Comment: @user3440845 you should include your HTML as well and use a Stack Snippet so we can help. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: you need to fire that bit of script once the document is fully loaded . example : `window.onload=function(){//your script }`

Comment: You need to get the value for `b` when any action on the page triggers the `.is-open`. Right now, it will check only once when the page loads.